# Understanding good habits with OOP and multiple inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have recently learnt that I haven't been practicing the best habits in OOP and have begun studying better habits for OOP.  So my question is this - should I limit how many things a class inherits to a certain amount?

An example to help explain.

Note: constructors and destructors are removed from example to save space.

```
class Object
{
 protected:
    /* common declarations */

 public:
    /* common functions */
}

class Collidable
{
 protected:
    /* common declarations */

 public:
    virtual void Collide() = 0;

    /* common functions */
}

class Animated
{
 protected:
    /* common declarations */

 public:
    virtual void Animate() = 0;

    /* common functions */
}

class Unit : public Object,  public Collidable, public Animated
{
 protected:
    /* common declarations */

 public:
    virtual void Collide() { /* Collide  */ }
    virtual void Animate() { /* Animate  */ }

    /* common functions */
}
```

In here, `class Unit` inherits the three classes above it, what I want to know is, how much should be limited when inheriting things? As in, `class Object : class, class, class... etc`.  Should the number of inherited classes be limited to a smaller amount and have classes made in-between that have already inherited some of the abstract base classes? I know this question is kind of meh, but I desire to keep good habits and I thank you for helping me if you can.

Also, any other advice for good habits in OOP and such would also be much appreciated.

Comment: The question is: what does this much inheritance buy you, other than the ability to subvert the type checker (which is a *bad* thing)? In particular, what purpose does an `Object` base class fill?

Comment: It is hard to answer since your question is too "not from our Universe". For example I have some 'Collidable' named 'x' and tell to it 'x.Collide()'. What does it mean?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: an `Object` base class' purpose is to provide basic functionality to all derived classes. This is done in [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx) and [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html).

Comment: @BobbyDigital And it is a terrible idea. C# and Java need it, not because of the basic functionality but because their type system used to be fundamentally tied to non-generic containers of references. In C++ that is not necessary due to templates. Offering “basic functionality” in a base class is a terrible idea: arbitrary types do not share functionality. For instance, giving all types an `Equals` method is just unnecessary and potentially error-prone.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - That actually isn't exactly my question, but more so, is it bad to do this? The code there is just to somewhat illustrate the skeleton of my question.  What I want to know is if it is a bad habit to inherit so many base classes and should there be classes in-between to help cut down how much you inherit like in the example above, should I make a `class CollidableObject: public Object, public Collidable` or should I leave the skeleton the way it is and make `Unit` inherit all the needed base classes?

Comment: Not sure if it's a coincident that your code looks game-ish, but there's a good amount of information concerning your topic in [Game Coding Complete](http://www.amazon.com/Game-Coding-Complete-Fourth-Edition/dp/1133776574). Head to your nearest B&N and read away.

@KonradRudolph: makes sense, suppose I'm just accustomed to it. It seems to me there are a few that are nice, but I agree probably unnecessary.

Comment: @BobbyDigital, Thanks for the recommendation, I do intend to specialize with game coding, but I like to just program in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my two cents on class hierarchies:

1. It is certainly not a good idea to define an interface class for each and every virtual function that might appear in two different classes. Those virtual function declarations should usually remain in the main inheritance tree *unless you have good reason to factor them out*.

   This usually means that you have only one class to inherit from, but you may occasionally get two or even three base classes. Don't avoid multiple inheritance altogether, it can be a great tool to solve some tricky situations, but try to minimize its use.
2. Deep inheritance hierarchies are also to be avoided. They tend to obfuscate the interfaces by effectively splitting a class definition across many different header files, forcing you to read *all* the direct and indirect base class declarations to figure out what a class can do.
3. Another problem that can arise is that you get too many universally used classes, which leads to an interplay between the classes that is too complex. Classes should be grouped into well connected clusters/modules with only a very small interface that is used from outside this cluster.

   In this respect, a module works a bit like another means of encapsulation on top of classes, that allows you to shortlist the publicly known classes. Modules are informal in C++, though. They might correspond to directories in the source tree, but neither is that a requirement for a module, nor is the presence of a directory a good hint that it contains a module. But it is a good idea to document your modules well.
4. But, most importantly, each class should provide a clear and concise interface that is as useful as possible in the client code that uses it. It should do one task, and do it well. If the class needs to do complicated things, it can use other classes behind the scenes (be a proxy for a module), but its interface should be as simple as possible.

Comment: This certainly helps a ton, but to help with some personal clarification, would my skeletal code up there be okay if `Unit` was used for inheritance later on? (ex `class Player : public Unit` and `class Enemy : public Unit`) Or is there a cleaner, better way? Thanks a ton for your time and help.

Comment: Whether you use `Unit` for inheritance later on, does not have any influence on whether it is defined in a good way. The question that you need to answer is: "Is there a class that needs to be `Collidable` without being an `Object` or `Unit`?" If no, factor `Collide()` into `Object` or `Unit`. If yes, go ahead and factor it out. But try to assemble meaningfull interface classes, try to avoid flooding your class hierarchy with a ton of trivial ones like `class Collidable { public: virtual void Collide() = 0; };`. One or two such classes is ok, but more than a handful starts to smell.

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much more sense to me now.  So I would presume that this is the case for any base, or parent, class as well?   If `Object` will only be used in `Unit` I might as well not make `Object` and put all of it's functions in `Unit` correct?

Comment: That depends on the complexity of the combined class, but yes, generally a flat hierarchy is preferable. You might also consider using a subclass (a class that is defined inside a class for implementation purposes) to separate concerns, or split the implementation in some other ways. As long as this split is a private implementation detail that does not add complexity to the interface, it has no negative effects.